# Is there a way to use azure artifacts-keyring authentication in non interactive mode? I want to install private py package(artifacts) in azure func

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-artifacts

How do I avoid this interactive way of authenticating?
[image]

Comment: Can you explain the 'artifact authenticationl

Comment: I am trying to download the python package(using pip in Azure function app) hosted in Azure artifact's(Azure DevOps). I know we can use PAT to do that along with extra index URL for package

Comment: But can we leverage artifact-keyring(non interactive) to do that.

Comment: I still have to try this one ARTIFACTS_KEYRING_NONINTERACTIVE_MODE. I Will update once I do that.

Answer (score 3):

Add PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL param to Function config with in-line PAT token:

```
https://<your-feed-name>:<your-PAT-key>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<your-organization-name>/<your-project-name>/_packaging/<your-feed-name>/pypi/simple/
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-keyring#environment-variables) on Github provides an environment variable：

`ARTIFACTS_KEYRING_NONINTERACTIVE_MODE`: Controls whether the underlying credential provider can issue interactive prompts.

You can see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems don't have a good way to install private packages in azure functions in non interactive mode.

Maybe you can choice a workaround, put the modules in the function app, and use relative reference to use the code in the modules.